# How to tell if custom pipe.transform() filtered value?

Tags: angular

I use a custom pipe to filter an array of groups and need to know if my pipe transformed the array, resulting in displaying the data differently. In this case expand all groups if the array has been filtered.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I have tried returning an object = { array, boolean } from the pipe, but do not know how to access and pass the boolean to my component.

```
<my-component *ngFor="let group of (some-array| arrayFilter: filterParam)" 
    [filtered]="trueIfPipeTransformedArray"></my-component>
```

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the result to a variable using `as` and compare if the length differs:

```
<my-component *ngFor="let group of (some-array| arrayFilter: filterParam) as result" 
    [filtered]="result.length != some-array.length"></my-component>
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)